# Cannot access Tomcat installed on GCE

Tags: tomcat, google-compute-engine, tomcat9, vpc, google-vpc

I've been trying to get Tomcat (specifically, Tomcat 9) running on a GCE along with enabling SSL to it with little success. I've run this configuration on another computer and I could do both of these things with no real complications.

What I've done/tried:

- Added an SSL connector to the `server.xml` file.
- Added the `address` attribute to both the preconfigured connector and the SSL connector as `0.0.0.0` in the `server.xml` file.
- Added a new firewall rule to enable ports `tcp 80, tcp 8080, tcp 8084(custom), udp 443, udp 8443`.
- Tried changing the Engine and Host from localhost to a named host.
- Marked `Allow HTTP traffic` and `Allow HTTPS traffic` on the VM Instance.

Here's what the firewall rule looks like:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzz9L.png)

However, I still cannot access Tomcat, neither on port `8080`/`8084`, nor through HTTPS (port `8443`), getting a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. I'm not sure what else I could shift around to get it work. I can access other resources using the IP address and the named host; just to add further context, something else is running on port `8080` and I can access it, so it makes sense that I cannot access Tomcat there, but `8084` should be free.

Does anyone know if I'm possibly missing something? I ran `iptables -L -v -n` and got the following:

```
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  628 32164 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:8080
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:8443
  102  4496 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:443
 1439 83204 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
  977 57800 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! I'm still somewhat of a newbie in both Tomcat and GCE, so maybe I'm just not seeing something.

**EDIT**: I've solved connecting to Tomcat through regular means, as I had forgotten to run `ufw allow` for the custom port I was using. However, I'm still having issues with connecting with SSL.

Comment: I forgot to run `ufw allow 8084` and I can now access tomcat through that port. However, I'm having no such luck with SSL yet. I tried changing the port to `8445`, using `ufw allow 8445` and updating the `server.xml` file to point to this port for the connector.